# Rebuild borg index file

Tags: backup

Borg backup host crashed while creating a new backup, and it looks as if the index-file is now broken:

> index.135979: Incorrect file length (expected 171652778, got 104857600)

Is that something that can be rebuilt somehow?

Server is running old borg 1.0.9 from debian/raspbian package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if `borg check --repair` solved this. Index-file was generated with correct size and I have made several new backups as well as been able to extract old and new backups from the repository.